# How to use custom Delphi function in FastReport 4?

Tags: delphi, function, fastreport

I want to use custom Delphi function in FastReport that I can use of the function for some frxMemoView in design time.
I find some suggestion in web such as Addfunction in fast report but I can't see my function in function tab in FastReport.
please help me.

Thanks
Hosein

Comment: Have you seen [`this guide`](http://goo.gl/AnGZ4) ?

Comment: Dear Lama I see this link before, I write this codes but till I can't see my function on function tab in fastreport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in then [Using Custom Functions in a Report](http://fast-report.com/documentation/DevMan/index.html?custom_functions_connection_to_report.htm) mentioned by TLama works nearly fine.

There a two problems you might have tripped over.

First: Documentation has two bugs in constructor TFunctions.Create; A missing begin, and a supernumerary '
the corrent implementaion would be

```
constructor TFunctions.Create;
begin
inherited Create(AScript);
with AScript do
   begin
   AddMethod('function MyFunc(s: String; i: Integer): Boolean', CallMethod,
            'My functions', ' MyFunc function always returns True');
   AddMethod('procedure MyProc(s: String)', CallMethod,
            'My functions', ' MyProc procedure does not do anything');
   end;
end;
```

The second "problem" is you can not expect to see the functions in the IDE by double clicking on the report, the selection is only availble if you call DesignReport at runtime. This option is not available in the limited edition shipped with XE3.

```
begin
   //......
   frxReport1.DesignReport;
  //......
end;
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks Bummi, I found my mistake. I thought that I can click on component then see the my function. I use in run time with designer and solve my problem.