# FastReport 5.3 Designer can't access events

Tags: delphi, fastreport, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm using **FastReport** version 5.3.14 in Delphi 10.1 Berlin.

I'm porting over a VCL app originally written on **DelphiXE**

When I open the report in the **FastReport Designer** clicking on the Events tab on the Object Inspector does nothing. I also can't click on the Code tab of the report. (see screenshot below)

[image: FastReport Screenshot]

I use the **MasterData1OnBeforePrint** event to dynamically load images.

Comment: Report event handlers are not available in Embarcadero Edition [link](https://www.fast-report.com/en/products/report-for-delphi-fastreport-4-feature-matrix.html/).

Comment: I was able to use the events in the FastReport 4 that came with DelphiXE.

Comment: Had the same problem as you Chucko, without events FR is unusable, but I understand from the vendor point of view, they need to sell something. Anyway, I went back to good old quickreport :)

Comment: Then you had a different version of FR4 than the EMBT Edition. The version included with the IDE has never supported report event handlers, which is the primary reason we never switched to using it - we couldn't do any reasonable testing of usability without purchasing the full version.

Comment: Try solve from Delphi see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015491/how-to-write-events-of-fastreport-band-in-delphi-code