# how can i combine cells in fastreport?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, fastreport

i have a table. to print like this
https://up.djelfa.info/uploads/155762484493151.png
I want to make the observation take the whole table means it remains empty. The empty box takes all the table.
https://up.djelfa.info/uploads/155762492124361.png
im working with fastreport 5 vcl
master data
https://up.djelfa.info/uploads/155762509600791.png

Comment: Please do not try to ask a question which consists merely of screenshots.  Instead, explain **in words** exactly what you mean by 'I want to make the observation take the whole table means it remains empty.'  You could start by explaining how that comment relates to the titlke of your q.  I'm voting to close this q until you correct this deficiency.

Comment: In my case I had a hard time coming up with the idea of ​​my problem. I explained it in pictures so that everyone could understand the problem in a short time.
Why write a lot if no one understands the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Per your last link, it appears that you have hard-drawn the cell lines in your master data row. This means they will print for each row.  There are, however, multiple ways to get around this:

1. Make the upper and lower lines for your Observation column separate objects (e.g. LineObsTop and LineObsBottom).  Then, in the MasterData Band's `OnBeforePrint`, adjust the visibility of these based on the values of the column
2. Don't hard-code cell lines!  Instead, make sure the cell fields all align perfectly and use the fields' `Frame` properties.  Then use the Observation field's `OnBeforePrint` to adjust the frame based on value.
3. Similar to #2, but use conditional formatting for the cell, adjusting the frame.

Comment: When I open the report in the FastReport Designer clicking on the Events tab on the Object Inspector does nothing. I also can't click on the Code tab of the report. When I open the report in the FastReport Designer clicking on the Events tab on the Object Inspector does nothing. I also can't click on the Code tab of the report. (see screenshot below.the same problem like this one her https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511457/fastreport-5-3-designer-cant-access-events

Comment: im using delphi10.2 tokyo .

Comment: Yes, if you are using the free version of FastReports which comes with Delphi (something you failed to mention), you do not have access to events and code.